# Foreach loop in AngularJS and $http.get

Tags: angularjs, get

I have problem with my AngularJS function. Data from first forEach is retrieved with `$http.get` and in second forEach, `$scope.products` isn't defined yet. I know that `$http.get()` is an asynchronous request and this is the point... But how to rewrite this function to work fine ?

```
$scope.getAll = function () {
    var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
    $scope.products = [];
    var i = 0;
 angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
     console.log("important1:" +  $scope.products);
        console.log("key: " + k + ", value:  " + v);
         ProductsService.retrieve(k).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.products = $scope.products.concat(response.data);
                        $scope.products[i].quantity = v;
                        i++;
         }, function (error) {
            console.log('error');
         });
  });
    console.log("important2:" +  $scope.products);

    angular.forEach($scope.products, function(value, key) {
        $scope.total = value.quantity*value.price + $scope.total;
        console.log("Quantiy: " + value.quantity);
        console.log("Price: " + value.price);
    });
    console.log($scope.products);
    console.log($scope.total);
};
```

Comment: Put all `ProductsService.retrieve`s in an array of promises and resolve using `$q.all([promises]).then(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up a list of service calls then call $q.all. Inside the then function you can put your second loop.

```
var listOfServiceCalls = [];
//Add to list of service calls

$q.all(listOfServiceCalls)
    .then(function () {
        //All calls completed THEN
            angular.forEach($scope.products, function(value, key) {
        $scope.total = value.quantity*value.price + $scope.total;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

More specifically, you would do:

```
$q.all([p1, p2, p3...]).then(function() {
    // your code to be executed after all the promises have competed.
})
```

where p1, p2, ... are the promises corresponding to each of your ProductsService.retrieve(k).